# Namer Server Propagation DELAY / Private DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, ns-record

I have the below setup at my registrar .

Main DOmain = **abc.com**
Second Domain = **def.com**
Third DOmain = **ghi.com**

As such , I have configured the below DNS / Host settings .

**abc.com**
NameServer : ns1.myhost.com & ns2.myhost.com
Hosts : ns1.abc.com & ns2.abc.com (both are pointing to my two IP addresses at my host.)

**def.com**
NameServer : ns1.abc.com & ns2.abc.com

**ghi.com**
NameServer : ns1.abc.com & ns2.abc.com

H/e it's been 72 Hrs since the initial changes and STILL the DNS Propagation is shown incomplete as per the below sites.

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?
https://www.nexcess.net/resources/tools/global-dns-checker

- My registrar is GoDaddy , And I initially (day1) replicated the same host entries on BOTH abc.com & def.com . H/e I found out and then setup the servers as above 50 Hrs ago.

** The records at ICANN is showing the NEW dns zone files :-)

Thanks & Best Regards,
Lakshitha Ab

Comment: Without the actual domain names to check the public records all anyone can realistically do is guess.  What are you expecting to see but not seeing?  'Incomplete' is a bit vague.

Comment: Main Domain (abc.com)  = hostmeraki.com

Second Domain (def.com) = codemeraki.com

Third Domain (ghi.com) = rbnsrilanka.org & rbnsrilanka.com

* By Incomplete , I'm referring to the fact that the NS records shown on the DNS Check sites I've mentioned reflect the OLD ns records I've configured for the respective domains (faceshared) .

But on the ICANN WHOIS page all the correct records (ns.hostmeraki.com) is showen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changed the `NS` records in the delegation information (in the parent zone, managed through your registrar) but the authoritative `NS` records (in your own zone) do not match.

Always make sure to verify that your changes are correct (by querying the authoritative servers) before you start to wait for caches to expire.

`dig +trace +add example.com NS` will demonstrate this type of error.

When following the chain of delegations the problem is quite clear in all three cases:

Delegation information

```
codemeraki.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns2.hostmeraki.com.
codemeraki.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns1.hostmeraki.com.
```

Authoritative information

```
codemeraki.com.         86400   IN      NS      ns2.faceresellerasia1.com.
codemeraki.com.         86400   IN      NS      ns1.faceresellerasia1.com.
```

Delegation information

```
rbnsrilanka.org.        86400   IN      NS      ns2.hostmeraki.com.
rbnsrilanka.org.        86400   IN      NS      ns1.hostmeraki.com.
```

Authoritative information

```
rbnsrilanka.org.        86400   IN      NS      ns1.faceresellerasia1.com.
rbnsrilanka.org.        86400   IN      NS      ns2.faceresellerasia1.com.
```

Delegation information

```
rbnsrilanka.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns2.hostmeraki.com.
rbnsrilanka.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns1.hostmeraki.com.
```

Authoritative information

```
rbnsrilanka.com.        86400   IN      NS      ns2.faceresellerasia1.com.
rbnsrilanka.com.        86400   IN      NS      ns1.faceresellerasia1.com.
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks a lot I got the issue sorted DNS propagation in the correct way has begun :)